# Checking a date is in an interval given by partial/periodic dates

Tags: c++, algorithm

I can define an interval with `start` and `end` in the format `YYMMDD`, but they can also be partial/periodic - meaning some elements (day, month or year) can be left blank.

For example, `start = "  1115"` and `end = "  0115"` the interval is 15th nov to 15th jan every year.

I want to check if a non-partial date is in the interval.

```cpp
int compareParial(const char* first, const char* second)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
    {
        if (first[i] != ' ' && second[i] != ' ' && first[i] != second[i])
            return first[i] > second[i] ? 1 : -1;
    }
    return 0;
}

bool isDateInInterval(const char* start, const char* end, const char* searchDate)
{
    int firstCompare = compareParial(start, searchDate);
    int endCompare = compareParial(end, searchDate);

    if (firstCompare <= 0 && endCompare >= 0)
        return true;

    // the date can still be in the interval if the start of the interval is in one year, but end in the next year
    bool switched = 0 < compareParial(start, end);
    if (switched && (firstCompare <= 0) != (endCompare >= 0))
       return true;

    return false;
}

int main()
{
    cout << boolalpha << isDateInInterval("  1115", "  0115", "251110") << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Update: If the dates are reversed check again if `searchDate` is in.

A problem I notice is what if `start` and `end` are reversed but the year is provided. For example: `isDateInInterval("200105", "190601", "251110")` would be `true`

Comment: What debugging have *you* done? Your function can return `true` two different ways. Have you determined which way it's happening? That would be the first step to debugging this issue.

Comment: @pcarter yes, the second way. start > end, but that isn't enough to say its in

Comment: Then the next step would be to look at the `for` loop  of `compareParial` to see what `i` is when it returns `1` and then what the corresponding values are in `first` and `second` for index `i`'s value. Looking at the code, it appears that it will be when `i` is 2.

Comment: Your code assumes that if the year is missing, the year is the same for `start` and `end`.

Comment: @pcarter you are right, but I don't it to do that

Answer (score 3):

C++20 contains types which can represent partial dates: `year`, `month`, `day`, `year_month`, `month_day`, etc.<sup>2</sup>

For example:

```
auto start = November/15;
auto end = January/15;
```

By using actual calendrical types, as opposed to strings, the logic you have to deal with can be greatly simplified.  A complete `year_month_day` might be compared against an interval defined by a pair of `month_day` like this:

```
bool
compare_partial(std::chrono::month_day start, std::chrono::month_day end,
                std::chrono::year_month_day searchDate)
{
    using namespace std::chrono;

    // Guess that both start and end fall in the same year
    auto trial_start = start/searchDate.year();
    auto trial_end = end/searchDate.year();
    if (trial_start <= trial_end)
    {
        return trial_start <= searchDate && searchDate <= trial_end;
    }

    // start/y > end/y
    // Otherwise guess that searchDate comes after trail_start:
    if (trial_start <= searchDate)
    {
        // trial_end must be in the next year
        trial_end += years{1};
        return trial_start <= searchDate && searchDate <= trial_end;
    }
    // Otherwise searchDate < start/y  && start/y > end/y
    // trial_start must be in the previous year
    trial_start -= years{1};
    return trial_start <= searchDate && searchDate <= trial_end;
}
```

Be forewarned that even this answer is somewhat wrong<sup>1</sup>.  However by using actual calendrical types to do things like add/subtract a year, and do the comparisons, one makes the code cleaner, easier to read, and thus less likely to contain errors.

This answer also only addresses the `month_day` partial date.  You might also have a `year_month` partial date, or a mixture of `month_day` and `year_month`.

`std::chrono` has no type `year_day`, and I'm not sure what that would mean anyway.  If you have an idea of what it would mean, I have no doubt that C++20 chrono could help you model it.

In any event:

```
cout << boolalpha << compare_partial(November/15, January/15, 2025y/November/10) << endl;
```

will output:

```
false
```

Even if you don't use C++20 chrono (or it's free preview), modeling this using calendrical types (perhaps of your own making), as opposed to strings, is highly recommended for creating a robust, error-free solution.

---

<sup>1</sup> Expressions such as `trial_end += years{1};` aren't guaranteed to be valid dates.  For example what if `trial_end` has the value 2020-02-29.  Adding a year to that will give you 2021-02-29.  To make this correct, you must decide how you want to handle such situations (e.g. map it to 2021-02-28?).

---

<sup>2</sup> There also exists a free, open-source, header-only preview of this part of C++20 which works with C++11/14/17:  https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date

Answer (score 0):

If year is set, and the dates are switched, you must return false, since it is an empty interval.

```
bool switched = 0 < compareParial(start, end);
if (start[0]==' ' && switched && (firstCompare <= 0) != (endCompare >= 0))
   return true;

return false;
```